# SQL Server recursive CTE query to find all items belonging to all categories and their descendants

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a bit confused trying to use a recursive CTE to list all the items in a product catalogue for all the categories *and* their respective parent categories that each item belongs to.

The tables are really simple...

- Table `Category`; Columns: Id, ParentID, Title
- Table `itemCategory`; Columns: ItemID, CategoryID

I am just struggling to work out how to get the results I want. My best attempt is not right:

```
WITH
CTE (itemID, categoryID, title) AS (
    SELECT itemID, categoryID, title
    FROM itemcategory
    INNER JOIN category ON category.ID = itemcategory.categoryID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT iI.ItemID, iI.categoryID, i.title
    FROM itemcategory iI INNER JOIN category i ON i.ID = iI.categoryID
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.categoryID = i.ParentID)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

I have a similar query which counts the number of items under each category:

```
WITH cte_count_category(id, parentid, c)
        AS (SELECT c1.id,
                c1.parentid,
                (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT itemid
                            FROM   itemcategory AS iI
                            WHERE  iI.categoryid = c1.id) AS t1) AS c
            FROM   category AS c1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT c2.id,
                c2.parentid,
                d.c
            FROM   category c2
                INNER JOIN cte_count_category d
                        ON c2.id = d.parentid)
SELECT cte_count_category.id,
        cte_count_category.parentid,
        title,
        Sum(c)     itemCount
FROM   cte_count_category
        LEFT JOIN category
                ON category.id = cte_count_category.id
GROUP  BY cte_count_category.id,
            cte_count_category.parentid,
            title
HAVING Sum(c) > 0
ORDER  BY itemcount DESC;
```

I just can't work out how to get it to list all the items. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The categories need to be n deep although it is unlikely that it will go beyond 4 levels most of the time.

The output I am looking for is one row per itemID per category it falls under so, an item in the 'music book' category would appear under both the 'music book' category and the 'book' category.

Comment: Can you please post a SqlFiddle with some sample data?

Comment: And edit your post to show the output you want.

Comment: Do you have multiple levels of category parents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic you need is confused by the items.  You don't actually need them in the CTE (you can join them in afterwards).  Alternatively, you can put them in the "base" part of the construct.  Only the categories are needed in the recursive part.

This may be what you are looking for:

```
WITH CTE (itemID, categoryID, title, parentid, lev) AS (
      SELECT ic.itemID, c.categoryID, c.title, c.parentid, 0
      FROM itemcategory ic INNER JOIN
           category c
           ON c.ID = ic.categoryID
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cte.ItemID, c.categoryID, c.title, c.parentid, cte.lev + 1
      FROM CTE INNER JOIN
           category c
           ON CTE.ParentID = c.categoryID
     )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks! I find it really confusing trying to visualise how the self-referring joins need to be made.